# Unable to login with Xorg using Active Directory

Tags: login, xorg, active-directory, kerberos

Recently i've installed an Ubuntu 18.04 VM on Hyper-V with enhanced session enabled.
Successfully joined it to Kerberos Realm in our corporate Active Directory.

While i am using "su - username" i am able to login with the user and it creates directory at "home/domain/user".

However i am not able to log in to the Ubuntu with session Xorg using users from the Active Directory, can log in only with the local administrator account.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging i was able to find a solution.
We need to do some edit on **xrdp.ini** file

> sudo vi /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini

**use_vsock** should be set to **false**

> use_vsock=false

in order to work with TCP protocol.

Also all of the new users created via Active Directory should be given sudo permissions

> sudo usermod -aG sudo your_domain_user

And as final step

> sudo /sbin/shutdown -r now

After the restart i was able to login with each user.